# jstl core tag forEach doesn't appeared on JSP

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl, jsp-tags

```
<h1>Customer Lists</h1>
<div>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach var="e" items="${listofcustomers}" begin="0">
            <c:url var="deleteLink" value="/deleteCustomer">
                <c:param name="customerId" value="${e.cust_id}" />
            </c:url>
            <c:url var="updateLink" value="/editCustomer">
                <c:param name="customerId" value="${e.cust_id}" />
            </c:url>
            <tr>
                <td>${e.cust_name}</td>
                <td>${e.cust_email}</td>
                <td>${e.cust_pw}</td>
                <td>${e.cust_phone}</td>
                <td>${e.cust_country}</td>
                <td><a href="${updateLink}">Update</a> <a href="${deleteLink}"
                    onclick="if(!(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete '))) return false;">
                        Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>


    </table>
    <a href="adminlist">Admin List</a>
</div>
```

this is the function of controller class

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView login(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer, BindingResult result) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        try {
            if (customer.getCust_pw().equals("")) {
                result.rejectValue("cust_pw", "error.empty.pw");
                mav = new ModelAndView("login");
            }
            else if (customer.getCust_email().equals("")) {
                result.rejectValue("cust_email", "error.empty.email");
                return mav = new ModelAndView("login");
            }
            else if (mapper.findByEmail(customer.getCust_email()) == null) {
                result.rejectValue("cust_email", "error.mismatch.email");
                mav = new ModelAndView("login");
            }
            else if (!customer.getCust_pw().equals(mapper.checkPw(customer.getCust_email()))) {
                result.rejectValue("cust_pw", "error.mismatch.pw");
                mav = new ModelAndView("login");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(mapper.getAllCustomer());
                mav = new ModelAndView("index");
                mav.addObject("listofcustomers", mapper.getAllCustomer());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mav;
    }
```

and here is the function of mapper.java

```
  @Repository
public class CustomerMapper {
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomer() {
        SqlSession session = MyBatilUtil.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession();
        List<Customer> customerList = session.selectList("getAllCustomer");
        session.commit();
        session.close();
        return customerList;
    }
```

I am still new in this spring mvc. i hope i you guys can help me with this problem.
When i try to run the code using spring MVC, the forEach doesn't shown in the page. I have declared taglib on the jsp. Is there anything wrong in my jsp? or may be the logic of controller part?

Comment: Show us the entire view and the controller responsible for passing data to that view. Also make sure your taglib looks like this `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

Comment: @maciejd i just edited the page, i dont really know if thats what u need to see, but thats all function that running for the page currently.

Answer (score 0):

to use JSTL try using the following

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```